# ListDensityPlot in Polar coordinates with a higher efficiency

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

I have data like this

```
f[r,theta]
```

and cells number are about 600*600 (uniform mesh)

The original data has the property of uniform mesh for `r` and `theta`. However, when I transfer them into Cartesian coordinates, this property disappeared and it became a 360,000-point data. Using `ListDensityPlot` was very slow.

Because I have to plot a lot of data of this kind, I wonder if there is any other methods to plot them in polar coordinates with higher efficient.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Take a look at `MaxPlotPoints`

Answer (score 10):

How about you make a `ListDensityPlot` as usual in the original polar coordinates and then transform the vertices to Cartesian coordinates.

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{r, θ, Sin[3 r] Cos[3 θ]}, {r, 0, 2 π, 2 π/100}, {θ, 0, 2 π, 2 π/100}], 1];
plot = ListDensityPlot[data]
```

[image]

```
transformGraphicsComplex[f_, g_] := 
 GraphicsComplex[f /@ First[g], Sequence @@ Rest[g]]
Graphics[transformGraphicsComplex[# /. {r_, θ_} :> {r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ]} &, First@plot]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If the following is reasonable or not depends on your points' geometry. Anyway:

```
(*generate the points (slow)*)
n = 600;
f[r_, t_] := r^2 Sin[6 t]
s = CoordinateTransform[ "Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", {{r1, t1, f[r1, t1]}}];
tab = Table[ Flatten[s /. {r1 -> r, t1 -> t}, 1], {r, n}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n}];

(*plot them(fast) *)
ListPlot3D[Flatten[RandomSample[tab, 10], 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't get defining `s` in terms of `r1`,  `t1` and then using `Rule` to replace `r1` with `r` and `t1` with `t`. Wouldn't `s = CoordinateTransform[
  "Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", {{r, t, f[r, t]}}]` work directly?

Comment: @JackLaVigne Yes, but this way is more clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

using Rahul's `data`

```
f = Interpolation[{#[[1 ;; 2]], #[[3]]} & /@ data];
DensityPlot[
 f[Norm[{x, y}], Pi + ArcTan[-x, y] ] , {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 
  2 Pi},
 RegionFunction -> (Norm[{##}] < 2 Pi &), PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]